# How to make use of facesContext 's setClientWindow(Window window) method to open new tab from baking bean

Tags: jsf

as i have read some question and answers regards to the server side redirect of url to a new client window / tab, i found `<h:form target="_blank">` is the best way to achieve this, but in my case i cant do this cause it will affect some other  implementations in my page. now i found there is setClientWindw() method for facesContext, have anyone worked with this, can anyone provide a solution to open new tab using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().setClientWindow();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

Comment: You might need to explain your problem a little better but it looks like you misunderstand the purpose of `ClientWindow`. That component doesn't directly open anything, it's more an identifier than anything else. Is the redirect action not triggered by a command component?

Comment: what all i need is just open a new tab from bean method with a new url, please forget about <h:form target="_blank" >, is not setClientWindow() a method for creating a new window on borwser, iam asking this because i have read some documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/ClientWindow.html

Comment: That's not how `ClientWindow` works. Nothing in the doc says that class will help to open a new tab/window. All it will do is help the context distinguish between different tabs on the same browser. Apart from setting the target on the form, your only other option is to set the `target` attribute on a `h:commandLink` (I'm assuming you're using a commandbutton currently)